# Google chrome form textbox limit

Tags: google-chrome

What is the text box limit for google chrome in characters.

Comment: Do you mean the maximum it can possibly be, or the default character limit if one is not explicitly specified in your code?

Comment: Enough to freeze my computer. (tested, at least 100,000 chars)

Comment: Maximum characters limit that Google chrome text box can accept.

Comment: Did you find an answer ? I'm wondering the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually unlimited (limited only by computer memory). You can limit it using the maxlength parameter though:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="32" />
```